# Using Custom Attributes to create a Role Checker

Tags: c#, wcf

Consider the following line of code being entered in Every Operation of my ServiceContract:

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrators")) 
    throw new Exception("You are not authorized to perform this operation");
```

In the future I would like to add more than just this, I might want to log the failed call somewhere. This would mean that I have to change the behavior in Every Operation that I have.

What I would like to do instead is create a custom attribute that I can have on my OperationContracts: `RequireMinimumRoleAttribute` that would look like this: `[RequireMinimumRole("Administrators"]`.

First of all, I want this to behave like the filter context in MVC, I want to check the Role **before** the actual operation is called. Is this possible?

Second of all, I would like to have another attribute that I put on my ServiceContract: `FallbackRequireMinimumRoleAttribute` which would be used if a `RequireMinimumRoleAttribute` was not specified on a certain Operation.

**Example**

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    public int Add(int a, int b);

    [OperationContract]
    public string Information();
}
```

**Implementation**

```
[FallbackRequireMinimumRole("Users")]
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    [RequireMinimumRole("Administrators")]
    public int Add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

    public string Information() { return "This is a calculator service"; }
}
```

In this case `Add` would require Administration priviligies and the `Information` operation would only require User priviliges.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: What authentication and role profile mechanisms are you using?

Comment: I am using asp.net membership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible way:

Implement a custom `IOperationInvoker` which wraps the existing `Invoker` in a `DispatchOperation`. It should simply do the authorization check before chaining to the original invoker to dispatch the operation. It will need a ctor which takes an `IOperationInvoker` (the one being wrapped), and the role name to check.

To install appropriate instances of the custom invoker when the WCF dispatcher runtime is built: implement `IOperationBehavior` on `RequireMinimumRoleAttribute`, and `IServiceBehavior` on `FallbackRequireMinimumRoleAttribute`. In each case the implementation of `ApplyDispatchBehavior` should navigate the `DispatcherRuntime` object to find the appropriate `Invoker` instance(s) to wrap and replace with the custom one.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your authentication\authorization providers but look at PrincipalPermissionAttribute if it can solve you problem. Check here [How to: Restrict Access with the PrincipalPermissionAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731200.aspx)

Comment: I am using the asp.net Membership Provider, I will have a look at that. However I would still like to add custom behavior and have my own Attribute.

Comment: @Filip: You need AOP postcompilation (such as Postsharp does) or dynamic proxies (as Castle project does) to be able to add behavior to your attributes. Why do you want to log that info. You are already logging at the top level of your application. You can differentiate there between exception types.